# Hoy to specify language in bitcore-mnemonic

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitcore

```
var Mnemonic = require('bitcore-mnemonic');
var entropy  = "11111111111111111111111111111111";
```

the bitcore-mnemonic command is:

```
mnemonic = Mnemonic._entropy2mnemonic(new Buffer(entropy, 'hex'), Mnemonic.Words.FRENCH);
```

https://bitcore.io/api/mnemonic/

But if the language comes from my database:

```
var language = "FRENCH";
```

How can I specify the language to Mnemonic.words ? Something like:

```
Mnemonic.Words.language
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Mnemonic.Words[language]